# Tableify returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, html-table

I am trying to use tableify in node JS to convert the following JSON Array into an html table:

```
[{"ID":"1", "Name":"John"},{"ID":"2", "Name":"Mary"}] (this is a subset of the array shortened for this post.  The format is the same)
```

And when I run:

```
var tableify = require('tableify');
var html = tableify(recordset);
        console.log(html);
```

This comes back:

```
<table><tbody><tr><td class="object"><td class="undefined"></td></td><td class="object"><td class="undefined"></td></td><td class="object"><td class="undefined"></td></td><td class="object"><td class="undefined"></td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Why won't it return the contents of the array?

Comment: ok !! but what is the question

Comment: your code have no problem, and it works fine to me

Comment: @Dean is right. your code has no problem.  you can test your code by creating new program. you will get your own solution